# Java - Unable to sort a user defined array after overriding Comparable's compareTo method

Tags: java, sorting, overriding, comparable, compareto

So, I am simply trying to test out how to use the `compareTo` method on my own types, and cannot get it to work for even the simplest of cases. My code (self explanatory) is below (it creates an array of 'numbers' from 15 -> 1 under the user defined type `TestType`. I would like it to be sorted 'naturally'.

```
public class TestType implements Comparable<TestType> {

public int n;

TestType(int _n) {
    n = _n;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(TestType otherType) {
    return this.n < otherType.n ? -1 : (this.n > otherType.n ? 1 : 0);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    TestType[] a = new TestType[15];
    for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
        a[i] = new TestType(15 - i);
        System.out.println(a[i].n);
    }
    a.sort();
}
}
```

If you can see why it doesn't work, please let me know :) .

Comment: can you post your sort method?

Answer (score 6):

I think you should write `Arrays.sort(a);`.

Comment: Ahh such a simple fix, thank you. Is there a reason why my type does not inherit those from the `Array` class if it is an array itself?

Comment: Well, you have to distinguish `Arrays` as an Object from array as a simple built type. Here your `a[]` isn't an Object so it doesn't inherit from `Arrays`.

Comment: Actually, `a[]` _is_ an `Object`, but it does not inherit from `java.util.Arrays` (note the s), as `Arrays` is a utility class which has nothing to with actual instances of arrays. And even if it did, `Arrays` does not have a `sort()` method with no parameters. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `Arrays.sort(a)` instead of `a.sort()`?